# Migrating to Ember 1.1x - Getting rid of ObjectController + ArrayController design

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm currently using Ember 1.8 and planning to migrate to Ember 1.12. I have gone through many videos and understood that I should follow Component based approach and get rid of `ObjectController` & `ArrayController` slowly. But, I couldn't able to crack down how to replace my `ObjectController` + `ArrayController` design with Component design.

The main reason I opted for `ObjectController` + `ArrayController` design at the first place was to do item toggle (expansion & collapse of  item list). How to do the same thing using components?

Answer (score 0):

Future-proofing your Ember 1.x code by @samselikoff.
https://gist.github.com/samselikoff/1d7300ce59d216fdaf97 (must be read with conversation).

This helps me. I would recommend to put this on ember blog site. Then Google and Youtube search for "Ember 2.0". (I assume you stay tuned with ember blog.)

PS I know this is very opinionated answer :)